# How can I overwrite an existing instance method from a module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know I can add new methods to models but I can't seem to overwrite an existing method. Here's what I have

In my User.rb

```
include ExtraMethods
def is_invisible?
  true unless self.active?
end
```

In my module

```
module ExtraMethods
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def user_extra_methods
      include ExtraMethods::InstanceMethods
    end
  end
  module InstanceMethods
    def is_invisible?
      true unless self.active? || self.admin?
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ExtraMethods)
User.send(:user_extra_methods)
```

What I want to happen is for the method in the plugin to override the method in the model. Any thoughts or references would be great, can't seem to find a good reference for this.

thanks!

J

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you declare the class members is important.

You're performing the plugin's `include` **before** the self.active? method is declared... The model declaration will always take precedence, since it was declared later.

You'll have to resort to something like this:

http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2006/4/26/new-in-rails-module-alias_method_chain